# Why is $F$ continuous?

Tags: probability, continuity

Why is the function:

$F: P(\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$, $F(X) = \int_X e^{-x} dx$ a continuous function? How to prove such a thing? Does it even make sense to talk about the continuity of such a function? I encountered this in a probability exercise, which introduces $F$ as probability set function associated to a random variable. There is a hint at the end of the exercise: $\lim_{n \to \infty} F(A_n) = F(\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n)$. Doesn't this require $F$ to be continuous, viewed in some appropriate way?

Comment: The notion of continuity depends strongly on the topology in the sets involved in the function. The topology of $\Bbb R$ is usually assumed to be the usual, but you should specify the topology of $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Is $X$ a subset of $\mathbb R$? shouldn't it at least be measurable?

Comment: @ajotatxe What is an appropriate topology for this situation?

Comment: Not all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are measurable (at least with respect to Lebesgue measure).

Comment: @user251257 I don't know what measurable means. But assume that it's so. Does this make any progress?

Comment: What about the topology on measurable set that induced by the metric $\rho(X,Y)=P(X\Delta Y)$ (measure of the symmetric difference of two sets)?

Comment: what is your definition of continuous function on sets?

Comment: @user251257 epsilon-delta definition but I don't know how to deal with sets that's why im asking.

Comment: @George You cannot choose $Y$. Continuity means "for *all* $Y$ in $\delta$ ball..." You have to work out continuity carefully. Check out [absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_the_Lebesgue_integral).

Comment: @A.G. sorry it has been long since I dealt with continuity definitions. I deleted my comment.

Comment: are you sure, that $X$ is really a subset of $\mathbb R$ and not of $(0, \infty)$? Otherwise $F$ would not be continuous for the metric @A.G. suggested, for example. Please make sure, which topology you are dealing with.

Comment: This problem is one from Hogg's IMS. It should be $(0,\infty)$ but I put $\mathbb R$ because I saw no difference. Assume it is what you said. How do I prove continuity?

Comment: @George let us assume that a sequence of sets converges if their indicator functions converge point wise almost everywhere. Dominated convergence theorem yields the statement.

Comment: @George If you include all of $\mathbb{R}$ you'll have to cope with the function sometimes being equal to $\infty$. For example $\int_{-\infty}^0{e^{-x}dx}=\infty$.